# How can a customer spend least money to buy clothes in a sales promotion(algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

There is a sales promotion in a clothing shop.Every cloth has a price and a free condition.The free condition means that if your order reach this price this cloth will be free.A customer want to bug some clothes,how can he spend the least money?He can bug those with a lot of orders.

#### input:

```
m    //this is how many clothes category the shop have
//follow m lines input clothes and it's price
...
//follow m lines input clothes and it's free condition
...
n   //how many clothes does the customer want to bug
//follow m items are clothes which the customer want to bug
```

### eg:

#### input:

```
3
//these three lines means if your order >= 300 you can get A freely 
//if >=400 you can get B...,the order should not include present
A 300
B 400
C 500       
//these three lines are ABC's price
A 300
B 400
C 500      
3
A B C
```

#### output:

```
700
A + B - > C 
//every order can get only one present
//A+B 's order is 700 ,so he can get C freely,save 500,this is the greatest method,
//if your order is  B+C get A freely,save 300,so it is not the greatest,not true
```

#### input:

```
3
A 300
B 400
C 500
A 300
B 400
C 500
4
A A B C
```

#### output:

```
800
A  - > A //A 's order is 300 ,so he can get A freely
C  - > B //C 's order is 500 ,so he can get B freely
```

This is my question,I can't solve it on online judge,so I have to ask it here.

Comment: Why example 1, not C: 500 -> get A / B freely?

Comment: require spend least money

Comment: So 500 > 700? In your first case, buy C will get both A and B for free. Or one buy can only get one more extra cloth?

Comment: only one,if the order reach 500 that you can get C ,A+B's order is 700,so you can get it

Comment: Tell us the constrains, how large can m, n, price be, or just share the original online judge link

Comment: this is my question,there is no oj.you can think m is 1000,n 10,total price is 1000000

Comment: one minute is allowed

Comment: then just use O(2^n * n) to bitmap all combinations of buy / not buy clothes, and check if it is valid (can get the not-bought clothes for free). Get the minimum total cost combination?

Comment: n 100,i was wrong

Comment: n is 100,O(2^n*n)is too big,I think it is DP question

Comment: @dredh sure, I think it's DP as well, you should put ALL above NEW information to your OP, it is kind of becoming a new question now

Comment: @shole whatever,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the complexity of this problem depends on exactly how you are allowed to buy the goods you want. I think it is easiest if you can present a set of goods that you will pay for, and then take free anything you want that is marked with a free threshold which is less than or equal to the amount of money you have handed over.

In this case there is an algorithm similar to the pseudo-polynomial knapsack algorithm which computes, for each possible total price P, the best way of selecting a set of goods to buy to add up to P. That is, the way of selecting a set of goods to buy that minimises the maximum free threshold price of any good not in that set that you want to buy. You need a table that gives you the value of that threshold for each possible P.

Consider the goods one by one, whether you want them or not, and at each stage build a table of answers based on the table of answers at the previous stage. Take the previous table and consider what happens if you buy or don't buy the current good and add it or not to the best answer for a given price in the previous table. If you buy it you have a possible best answer for an increased price. If you don't buy it you may increase the maximum free threshold associated with that best answer, if the free threshold for the current good is greater than the maximum free threshold for a good not bought associated with the answer you are considering, and if you actually want the current good.

Once you have a final table of best answers for each P you can backtrack to find out what set of goods make up that P. Then look to see if there is any good that you want not in that set whose free threshold is greater than P. If not, then this is a possible answer, and you clearly want the one associated with the smallest value of P.